# Javascript Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty returning incorrect value for IE9+ when using YUI attribute default value

Tags: internet-explorer-9, yui, internet-explorer-10, hasownproperty

I believe that I've found a bug in IE9+ and/or YUI 3 with the hasOwnProperty javascript method.  I'm wondering if anyone here has seen this problem before or if you are able to isolate the problem further.  I'd like to inform the relevant party/parties about this problem but I can't figure out if I need to contact the IE team or YUI.

**Details:**

When IE9/IE10 is :

- rendering in standards mode
- an initialized YUI attribute is involved (line 11 in the example code)

hasOwnProperty returns the incorrect value for an object that contains keys that are not valid javascript identifiers (b in a.b is OK, 5 in a.5 is invalid).  Valid identifiers do not have this problem.

**Example code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyakadizzy/nLZJy/6/ (remember that this problem only occurs in IE9/IE10)

```
YUI.add("ie9-hasOwnProperty-test", function (Y) {

        function IE9HasOwnPropertyTest(config) {
            IE9HasOwnPropertyTest.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        Y.mix(IE9HasOwnPropertyTest, {
            NAME : "IE9HasOwnPropertyTest",
            ATTRS : {
                attributeWithNumericProperty : {
                    value : {}
                },
                attributeWithStringProperty : {
                    value : {}
                }
            }
        });

        Y.extend(IE9HasOwnPropertyTest, Y.Base, {

            initializer: function (config) {
                // Uncomment this section below the problem will be "fixed".  The problem appears to be related to attribute initialization.
                // this.set("attributeWithNumericProperty", {}); 
                var attributeWithNumericProperty = this.get("attributeWithNumericProperty");
                attributeWithNumericProperty['1234'] = 999;
                GLOBAL_attributeWithNumericProperty = attributeWithNumericProperty;

                // If the object property is an identifier can be set after a dot (e.g. a.b) then the problem will not be hit
                var attributeWithStringProperty = this.get("attributeWithStringProperty");
                attributeWithStringProperty['a1234'] = 999;
                GLOBAL_attributeWithStringProperty = attributeWithStringProperty;
            }
        });
        Y.IE9HasOwnPropertyTest = IE9HasOwnPropertyTest;
    }, "3.0.0", { requires : ["widget"]});
```

Running `new Y.IE9HasOwnPropertyTest(); GLOBAL_attributeWithNumericProperty.hasOwnProperty('1234');` will return false when it should return true.

Comment: Very interesting! It seems to happen not with "invalid identifiers" but rather with numbers as strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird behavior. I need to do a bit more research to find out why it's happening, but it seems to be a consequence of the way YUI handles default values when they're objects. YUI tries to clone the object to prevent this from happening:

```
function MyClass() {
  MyClass.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
Y.extend(MyClass, Y.Base, null, {
  ATTRS: {
    foo: {
      value: []
    }
  }
});

var obj1 = new MyClass();
var obj2 = new MyClass();

obj1.get('foo').push('bar');
console.log(obj2.get('foo')); // ['bar'] oops!
```

You can fix it by not using an object as a default value and instead using a function that returns a new object. This way you'll always get a new object and YUI won't try to be too smart:

```
MyClass.ATTRS = {
  foo: {
    valueFn: function () {
      return {};
    }
  }
};
```